# Shell using sed to remove file extension from find results

Tags: bash, shell, sed, find

I am trying to run

```
find . \ -type f -name "*.sh" -exec basename {} \; | sed "s/.sh/ "
```

to display all files in the currenty directoy, and subdirectories, that end in .sh.  I use `-exec basename {}` to remove the location of the file, so I just get the filenames themselves.  The find command is working fine, but when i pipe it into `sed "s/.sh/ "` I get an error message `sed: 1: "s/.sh/ ": unterminated substitute in regular expression`.  I am trying to replace the `.sh` extension with nothing, so I just get filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only missing the close `/` on sed.

```
find . -type f -name "*.sh" -exec basename {} \;  | sed "s/\.sh//"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great, but unfortunately after it prints the file names, it prints `find: -type: no such file or directory .

find: f: no such file or directory`
Edit:  Saw the edit, thanks a bunch this works great!

Comment: The problem is the ```\``` character right after the ```find . ```. Just drop it. I change the response to reflect.

Comment: I have this in a shell file called `find_sh.sh`.  Any idea why when I run `./find_sh.sh | cat -e` it prints `find.sh$` instead of the expected `find_sh$`?

Comment: Escape the dot ```sed "s/\.sh//"```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great, but why?  what is the difference between this, and just omitting the dot?

Comment: The dot inside sed mean {replace the dot position by any single character}. So sed finds the (_sh) and it matches. The remainder is .sh (which is a match) , but you instructed se only to replace the first match (one need to add the option /g to replace all matches). So,  for sed to understand the dot literally it has to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

`basename` can remove the extension for you.

```
find . -type f -name '*.sh' -exec basename {} .sh \;
```

Note this will work for *all* valid file names, not just ones that don't contain a newline.

If your `basename` command supports it, you can use the `-s` option to minimize the number of calls to `basename` you need.

```
find . -type f -name '*.sh' -exec basename -s .sh {} +
```

This allows multiple file names to be passed to each call to `basename`.